# Why does my node.js server not receive the socket io emit?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I am currently trying some stuff with socket.IO.
But for some reason I am not receiving the emit from the client.
I am using Node.js and express to host the html files.

Here is my current code:
server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var d = new Date();
var temp = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  app.use(express.static('public'));
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(temp + ' :A User connected');
  console.log('Socket ID: ' + socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log(temp +' :A User disconnected');
      console.log('Socket ID: ' + socket.id);
        socket.on('testCon', function(){
          console.log('Received');
        });
  });
});



http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sockets Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Socket Test Site</p>
    <button onclick="newConnection();">Connect</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction();">Execute</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
var socket;

function newConnection() {
  socket = io();
}

function myFunction() {
  socket.emit('testCon', null);
  console.log("Button Pressed");
}
```

I am not sure what the problem is right now.

Thank you!

Comment: you have your `socket.on()` call in your disconnect() callback

Comment: Thank you very much now it works! Didn't notice that.